# how to pass "Data Flow/Data Set" parameters to azure data factory pipeline from Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-sdk-python

From the below link, I understand using Python SDK, we can create Pipeline and run it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python

But I have tried to pass data flow  parameters in parameters={} in create_run function and it is not working.
(Looks like it is taking pipeline parameters and not data flow parameters)

Any example/ details would help!!

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: credentials = UserPassCredentials('userid','pwd')
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
df = adf_client.factories.get(rg_name, df_name)
p_name='DATA_STAGE'
run_response = adf_client.pipelines.create_run(rg_name, df_name, p_name, parameters={"Table_name":"FILE_INFO","Target_Query":"select * from schema1.FILE_INFO where cast(adf_create_date as date) in ('2020-12-17','2020-12-16') ","Application_name":"ACAL"})
run_response.run_id
pipeline_run = adf_client.pipeline_runs.get(rg_name, df_name, run_response.run_id)
print(pipeline_run.status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to do this. As a workaround, you can create pipeline parameters then pass them to Data Flow. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Steve. Yes that worked. I have created a pipeline parameter and passed that parameter to data flow.